# How do I export multiple pivot tables from python using pandas to a single csv document?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Say I have a function pivots() which aggregates pivot tables

```
def pivots():
    d = data() #another function which cleans up my raw data
    price_floor = PF(d)
    no_floor = NF(d)
    return price_floor,no_floor
```

I know how to export a single pivot table

```
q,r = pivots()
q.to_csv('C:\\export.csv')
```

But it would be so much more convenient if I could export both price_floor and no_floor to the same document 'export.csv'

Comment: Can you concatenate the two files after export?

Comment: I believe so, they will have the same dimensions

Comment: If you don't pass a path then to_csv() will return a string, so you could concatenate your two outputs and then write the resulting string out to file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_csv(path, mode='a')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to append files.

```
# default 'w' write mode
q.to_csv('C:\\export.csv')

# explicitly specify 'a' append mode
r.to_csv('C:\\export.csv', mode='a')

# Use header=False
# if you don't want to write headers while appending
r.to_csv('C:\\export.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: Yep, probably need to set `header=False` on all the appended tables as well.